# Edit tags on migrated question

Tags: support, status-completed, tags, migration, editing

[This question](https://superuser.com/questions/264822/visual-studio-how-to-auto-create-interface-from-class-with-comments-migrated) has been migrated to Stack Overflow (you'll probably have to search on [macro] to see the stub), and now because of the bad decision to link it directly to that question on SO, it can't be edited.

I was cleaning up the [macro](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/macro) moving the six questions to [macros](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/macros) and found that I could not clean up that question stub.

How exactly are we supposed to be able to edit that stub?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[macro](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/macro) has been removed and assigned as a synonym for [macros](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/macros)

You could flag such posts in future. Migrated questions are locked and hence not available for editing ( except for  ♦ anyway)

Comment: You __CAN'T__ flag posts that are just stubs.  It's another Stack Exchange bug/loophole.  This post is my flag.

Comment: @LanceRoberts You most certainly can http://i.imgur.com/53p9N.png

Comment: @Sathya, No, you most certainly can't.  As soon as you click on the question, you're taken to the other site.  I could never get into the Super User question stub.  Maybe you mods can, so you don't realize it, but that's how it works for us little people.

Comment: @LanceRoberts I'm not a mod on SO. Once you're on the migrated site, clicking on "migrated from..." takes you back to the original site with `?noredirect=1` parameter, so you remain on that page.  Confirmed this works for an unregistered user/visitor as well.

Comment: @Sathya, now that's a cool trick, not real intuitive, but I'll remember it.  I should go find a `hidden features of Stack Overflow` post and add that.

Comment: @Sathya I do that all the time, I thought everyone knew how to do that?

Comment: @studiohack so did I!